# sqlite3 Null Foreign Key won't be accepted through .import

Tags: sql, import, sqlite

I'm trying to populate a DB with some data and this particular Foreign Key can be present or empty (null?). Therefore, this is what I'm using:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;

CREATE TABLE TABLE1(t1 text NOT NULL, t2 text NOT NULL, fl1 float NOT NULL,
nullable_fk text NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (t1, t2), FOREIGN KEY (nullable_fk ) REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE(nullable_fk )
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE(nullable_fk text NOT NULL, var integer, PRIMARY KEY (nullable_fk));
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE(nullable_fk, integer) VALUES ("asd", 123);

CREATE TABLE AUX_TABLE(t1 text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (t1));
INSERT INTO AUX_TABLE(t1) VALUES ("bla");

INSERT INTO TABLE1(t1, t2, fl1, nullable_fk) VALUES ("bla", "bla", 1.1, NULL);
```

This is working fine. However if I try importing, it will fail:

```
File being imported (file name test.txt):
"ble"^"646"^0.170^NULL

Commands being used:
.separator ^
.import test.txt TABLE1

RESULT -> test.txt:1: INSERT failed: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

If after that I try doing **INSERT INTO** with the values from the file, it will work just fine.

Does anyone knows what is the catch with the **.import** command?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've seen from other pages that importing NULL wont work from CSV files, which is kind of what I was trying to do, and the recommendation would be to put a value in there and update afterwards. However, since the Foreign Key must be present in the other table (PARENT_TABLE), would the correct way to do this be to create a "temporary garbage entry" in PARENT_TABLE, use this in place of the NULL keys, update the keys to NULL and then delete this entry from PARENT_TABLE?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.import` imports text files, so it is not possible to have NULL values: you get an empty string, or the string "NULL" if you try to spell it out.

You can import the file into a [temporary](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temp_databases) table, adjust any 'wrong' values in there, and then copy to the actual table.

Alternatively, you can temporarily [disable foreign key checking](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys).

Comment: Even if I disable foreign key checking, I still won't be able to pass NULL to the table, right? But I could pass a "NULL" string and then update it to NULL. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: **By the way, this is what I did:** I didnt wanted to disable foreign key checking, so I created an entry on PARENT_TABLE as **("", 0)** (my csv file has empty strings where it should be NULL), imported test.txt into TABLE1 and finally **UPDATE TABLE1 SET nullable_fk = NULL WHERE nullable_fk = "";** and then **DELETE FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE nullable_fk = "";**